# Изменение значений точек в графике OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, oxyplot

Имеется программа, каждую секунду добавляющая в график точку с произвольным значением оси Y, но координата точки по оси X всегда больше на 1 чем предыдущая координата точки по оси X соответственно. С ходе работы программа добавляет в график добавляет множество точек, притом что в окне графика отображается всего 60 (остальные просто не нужны, так как данные устаревают). Возможно конечно есть какие-то другие способы не загромождать график, я буду благодарен если что-то предложите, но я решил просто создать 60 точек, шестидесятой задавать произвольное значение, а после итерации, пятьдесят девятой точке задать значение шестидесятой точки ДО итерации, таким образом создается иллюзия движения графика, но притом график не загромождается. Так вот, как можно изменить координаты произвольной точки, обратившись в к ней по её индексу в массиве DataPoint? 

Пробовал обращаться так:

```
mainmodel.dwgraph.Points.ElementAt(1).X
```

Но это поле доступно только для чтения.

Comment: Используйте привязку и выберите более удобную коллекцию, например Queue или LinkedList

Comment: Если вы о поле `X`, то вам нужно обновить всю точку + самостоятельно вызвать перерисовку графика